# Why is my method being called twice?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml

I'm working with HTML forms that are connected to a database via an REST API. The server work is handled with Coldfusion, mainly in cfscript syntax.

The form data is submitted in two or more sets per form. Most of the forms are long and performance dictates submitting ~70 fields per set. Splitting the record between create and updates also allows for duplicate checking by passing the form response ID in the initial call and checking for it in subsequent updates as the form is completed.

When an incoming form initializes the application, the form response ID is queried. If there's no match, then it's a new record. If there is a match, the record is updated using the database record ID. I currently have this logic set up in an if statement and two records are being created in the initial call. I've tried a few variations on attempts to solve this including checking other variables, switch statements, do/while loop, nested if statements, etc. In each case two records rather than one is created. Subsequent calls update the latest of the two records and no new records are created.

```
<cfscript>

    // Setup the qb object to call add and update methods 
qb = new components.qb();

    // Setup query object. In this case we're passing Response ID parameters to compare against. This allows us to check whether the incoming request represents a new record or an update.
qbQuery = new components.qbQue().qFieldValue(#qb_tableID#, #qb_token#, #uField#, #uValue#, #uList# );

    // An array of returned records, empty if new record
qbRecords = qbQuery.getQbRecords();

    // The latest Record ID to edit
qbLatest = qbQuery.getLatestRecord();

writeOutput("qbRecords is #arrayLen(qbRecords)# long! <br>");


if (arrayLen(qbRecords) == 0) {

    add_record = qb.addRecord(qb_tableID, qb_token, form_data);

} else {

    edit_record = qb.editRecord(qb_tableID, qbLatest, qb_token, form_data_edit);

}

</cfscript>
```

[EDIT] addRecord() function

```
public any function addRecord(qb_tableID, qb_token, form_data) 
{
    variables.qb_ticket = SESSION.qbTicket
    ;
    http
    method = "POST"
    result = "qbReturn"
    url = "#variables.qbUrl#/#qb_tableID#?act=API_AddRecord&ticket=#variables.qb_ticket#&apptoken=#qb_token#&#form_data#"
    ;
    this.setUuid(CreateUUID());
    this.setQbResult(XmlParse(qbReturn.Filecontent));
    this.setQbAction(Trim(QbResult.xmlRoot.XmlChildren[1].XmlText));
    this.setQbErrCode(Trim(QbResult.xmlRoot.XmlChildren[2].XmlText));
    this.setQbErrText(Trim(QbResult.xmlRoot.XmlChildren[3].XmlText));
    this.setQbRid(Trim(QbResult.xmlRoot.XmlChildren[4].XmlText));
    this.setQbUpdateid(Trim(QbResult.xmlRoot.XmlChildren[5].XmlText))
    ;
    return ( this )
    ;
}
```

[EDIT] The above function is refactored from the following createRecord() function. Among the changes the current addRecord() function passes data to the API in a URL where the old code submitted XML. That shouldn't be the issue but I'm calling it out as a significant difference.

The other significant difference is that createRecord() doesn't create two records.

```
<cffunction name="createRecord" returntype="any" access="public" output="false" description="Create new record">
    <cfargument name="qbURL" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="tableID" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="newRecord" type="xml" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="theTicket" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="theToken" type="string" required="true" />
    <!--- Add Record --->
        <cfhttp url="#qbURL#/#tableID#?" method="post" charset="utf-8" result="addRecord">                              
            <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#newRecord#" />
            <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Content-Type" value="application/xml" />
            <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
            <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Content-length" value="#len(newRecord)#"/> 
            <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="act" value="API_AddRecord">
            <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="ticket" value="#theTicket#">
            <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="apptoken" value="#theToken#">
        </cfhttp>
    <cfreturn addRecord.Filecontent />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: When you think the method is being called twice, what is the writeoutput() telling you about the arraylen?

Comment: That writeOutput() returns 0 for a new request and 2 on subsequent requests. If I re-invoke the query in the if statement under the add_record call, I can then writeOutput(arrayLen(qbRecords)) on the updated array. This returns two on an initial create call where it should return 1.

Comment: If you call `qb.addRecord()` separately from the file shown above, does it add the record twice?

Comment: Yes, @imthepitts, it does add the record twice. Updating my question to include addRecord() function.

Comment: I don't see anything about this that would cause it to run twice. I suspect the problem is internal to the `API_AddRecord` action within the API. Do you have access to that code?

Comment: I agree with @imthepitts, it's almost certainly a problem at the other end. If you're running this code on your dev machine, you could try proxying your http call in addRecord() through something like Fiddler to check that there's no funky redirects or odd response body coming from the API you're calling

Comment: I proxied the HTTP request and created one record. I've also been using the API_AddRecord action for some time without this type of issue. The addRecord() function represents a refactoring of similar code. I'll edit my question to the function that was refactored.